# Upload e mostrar na tela em tempo de execução do loop com PHP, Jquery, AJAX, javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, loop, upload

Quero fazer upload de um array e ao mesmo tempo quero mostrar cada arquivo que foi "upado" num ciclo, em tempo de execução do loop, (para isso a página não pode dar refresh), evitando de fazer todo o upload e depois carregar na tela os arquivos. Procuro não só uma maneira de fazer isso, mas também uma lógica para criar um sistema igual a isso que citei.
Eu quero fazer tipo assim:

```
Foreach (inicia o loop) {
bla,bla,bla começa o upload bla, bla
echo "upload concluido" e que apareça os dados do upload
}
```

E então reinicia e faça isso com todos os arquivos.

Comment: Você não tem código? Qual sua dúvida?

Comment: Desculpa pela demora, eu não possuo o código, pois eu não tenho ideia de como vou fazer.

Comment: A minha dúvida é como vou fazer para fazer esse _upload_, contextualizando, eu tenho um _array_ de 100 linhas mais ou menos, no antigo _script_, ele pega faz o _upload_ desses 100 arquivos, daí carrega uma página mostrando todos  os arquivos que _"upei"_, mas o que eu queria era assim:
Que inicia-se o _upload_ (usando um _ for_), porém em cada arquivo_ "upado"_ ele já carregasse o resultado na tela, e que fizesse isso para cada ciclo do _loop_.

Comment: Deixe-me esclarecer uma coisa, esse array, é um array de arquivos, correto? Você vai subir N arquivos para o servidor, e queria fazer um controle disso. É isso?

Comment: Isso, gostaria de achar um jeito da minha ideia funcionar, que cada vez que "upasse" mostraria o nome do arquivo "upado", fazendo isso com todos os arquivos..

Comment: Certo, vou te sugerir como resposta

Comment: Editei sua pergunta para ficar mais clara.